# How to get the current root URL on JSP

Tags: html, css, jsp

I need to dynamically get the root URL from a page to set as part of the Open Graph tags that will fetch the desired image. The closest I got was with ${request.requestURL}, but it returns the whole URL, like:

https://localhost:8080/abc/123/example/example.jsp

But I would like for it to return just the root URL, like:

https://localhost:8080/

Is there a way to do this?

This is the header of a page that will be the product page of a e-commerce. So, I would need to get the root URL of whatever part of the website the user is in to fill in with the product-specific URL. I've tried lots of methods, like ${request.requestURI} and ${request.contextpath} but none of them return what I want.

Comment: And what value has been return with ${request.contextpath}? Did you try to use **${pageContext.request.contextPath}?**

Comment: Yes, I've tried, it returns only part of the url. In the example I made, it would return /abc/123/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if it's the optimal solution, but I achieved what I needed assembling the url like this:

`${pageContext.request.scheme}://${pageContext.request.serverName}:${pageContext.request.serverPort}`